# Downgrade software version with InstallShield

Tags: .net, installshield

My latest released program is version 2.0.1.0, but since it's just in beta I wanted to change our software version to 0.3.0.0.

I changed the product code and changed the version number to 0.3.0.0. I also removed the isPreventDowngrade. I also added a major upgrade item that upgrades on a product version from 0.0.0.0 to 3.0.0.0, so it should upgrade all the programs.

I also make it that it completely uninstalls before installing a new setup.

When I install the new project, it keeps the old assemblies in the folder (.Net)

The project type is basic MSI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made it work by going in the "Application Data/Files and Folders" tab, selecting all the destination files (especially the primary outputs), right clicking them and selecting "Always overwrite".

I tried without doing this step and it would uninstall all the assemblies and not install the 0.3.0.0 assemblies since they were of a lower version.

I hope this helps anyone that encounters the same problem.